VersionedTransaction too large
I'm trying to execute a series of swaps, returned by Jupiter as a single atomic transaction.
Is contains following instructions

token_ledger_instruction
compute_budget_instructions
setup_instructions
swap_instruction
cleanup_instruction

All returned by Jupiter swap_instructions.
Than I do a transaktion
    let message = MessageV0::try_compile(
        &wallet,
        &swap_instructions,
        &[], // No address lookup tables for now
        recent_blockhash,
    )?;

    let transaction = VersionedTransaction::try_new(
        VersionedMessage::V0(message),
        &[signer], // Explicitly specify the type
    )?;

and it all fails with
base64 encoded solana_sdk::transaction::versioned::VersionedTransaction too large: 4864 bytes (max: encoded/raw 1644/1232)
How to workaround it?

There's no magic solution unfortunately -- you have to split up your transaction or use address lookup tables.
